# Bootstrap carousel function call

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

If you view the bootstrap carousel documentation, and view the page source. There are not any  function  calls on it and their carousel works fine from the start. Why do I need to add a function call if they dont?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The carousel is being called from a separate script file, `application.js`, line 97:

```
// carousel demo
$('#myCarousel').carousel()
```

In reality you don't need the call at all, you just need to have it there so your carousel starts sliding on page load. If you omit the call, it will be static until you hit the pager.